# Show a nested model by default in RailsAdmin

Tags: nested-forms, rails-admin

How would I go about showing a nested resource by default when editing an entry in RailsAdmin? Currently it exists as a button that you have to click to show the contents.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for this but ultimately ended using javascript to show the nested form by default. Following I have used:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#partner_api_account_attributes_field .toggler').click();
}, 100);
```

In rails_admin forms, nested resources are shown within a div with ID something like '#partner_api_account_attributes_field' where Partner was my model associated to ApiAccount. And ".toggler" is class name of the link that toggles the nested resource form.

I hope this helps. Thanks!